# How to call a certain function inside an if statement in python?

Tags: python, function

I am relatively new to python, in my foundation year I learned BBC BASIC which is pretty basic and I acquired many bad habits there. 
I learned python with the aid of codecademy, however, how can I call a function inside an if statement? In my first if statement I called the function `mainMenu(menu)`, however, it is not displaying the function contents. Why?

(By the way I am just trying to do an ATM Machine just to practice some of the things I learned and consolidate it

```
print "Hello ! Welcome to JD's bank"
print
print "Insert bank card and press any key to procede"
print
raw_input()

passcode = 1111

attempts = 0

while passcode == 1111:

    passcodeInsertion= raw_input("Please insert your 4-digit code: ")
    print""


    if passcodeInsertion == str(passcode):
        print "This is working" #testing-----
        print ""
        mainMenu(menu)


    elif attempts < 2:

        print "Sorry ! Wrong passcode"
        attempts += 1

        print "------------------------------------------------"
        print ""
        print"Try again !! This is your " + str(attempts) + " attempt"
        print
        print "------------------------------------------------"
        print   

    else:
        print""
        print "Your card is unfortunately now blocked" 
        exit()

def mainMenu(menu):

    print "------------------------------------------------"
    print "Select one of this options"
    print "1. Check Balance"
    print "2. Withdraw Money"
    print "3. Deposit Money "
    print "0. Exit "
    print "------------------------------------------------"
```

Comment: `mainMenu(menu)` Well, you don't have menu defined anywhere, so that's going to crash. Other than that, there shouldn't be any issues.

Comment: @MorganThrapp He has to move the function to the top else its not detected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print "Hello ! Welcome to JD's bank"
print
print "Insert bank card and press any key to procede"
print
raw_input()

def mainMenu():

    print "------------------------------------------------"
    print "Select one of this options"
    print "1. Check Balance"
    print "2. Withdraw Money"
    print "3. Deposit Money "
    print "0. Exit "
    print "------------------------------------------------"

passcode = 1111

attempts = 0

while passcode == 1111:

    passcodeInsertion= raw_input("Please insert your 4-digit code: ")
    print""


    if passcodeInsertion == str(passcode):
        print "This is working" #testing-----
        print ""
        mainMenu()


    elif attempts < 2:

        print "Sorry ! Wrong passcode"
        attempts += 1

        print "------------------------------------------------"
        print ""
        print"Try again !! This is your " + str(attempts) + " attempt"
        print
        print "------------------------------------------------"
        print   

    else:
        print""
        print "Your card is unfortunately now blocked" 
        exit()
```

Try the above. Moved mainMenu to the top and you don't need any parameters.

Comment: Thank You ! Learning everyday.

Answer (score 4):

Try putting the `MainMenu` function at the top. This is because in Python, function definitions have to be before their usage. Also, you never defined `menu`, so we can just get rid of it.

```
def mainMenu():
    print "------------------------------------------------"
    print "Select one of this options"
    print "1. Check Balance"
    print "2. Withdraw Money"
    print "3. Deposit Money "
    print "0. Exit "
    print "------------------------------------------------"

print "Hello ! Welcome to JD's bank"
print
print "Insert bank card and press any key to procede"
print
raw_input()

passcode = 1111

attempts = 0

while passcode == 1111:

    passcodeInsertion= raw_input("Please insert your 4-digit code: ")
    print""


    if passcodeInsertion == str(passcode):
        print "This is working" #testing-----
        print ""
        mainMenu()


    elif attempts < 2:

        print "Sorry ! Wrong passcode"
        attempts += 1

        print "------------------------------------------------"
        print ""
        print"Try again !! This is your " + str(attempts) + " attempt"
        print
        print "------------------------------------------------"
        print   

    else:
        print""
        print "Your card is unfortunately now blocked" 
        exit()
```

Answer (score 2):

As in C++, the function must be defined before the code area where it is used. Thus, your code should read:

```
def mainMenu():

    print "------------------------------------------------"
    print "Select one of this options"
    print "1. Check Balance"
    print "2. Withdraw Money"
    print "3. Deposit Money "
    print "0. Exit "
    print "------------------------------------------------"

print "Hello ! Welcome to JD's bank"
print
print "Insert bank card and press ENTER to proceed"
print
raw_input()

passcode = 1111
attempts = 0

while passcode == 1111:
        passcodeInsertion= raw_input("Please insert your 4-digit code: ")
    print
    if passcodeInsertion == str(passcode):
        print "This is working" #testing-----
        print ""
        mainMenu()  #removed menu as you have not defined it above
    elif attempts < 2:
        print "Sorry ! Wrong passcode"
        attempts += 1

        print "------------------------------------------------"
        print ""
        print"Try again !! This is your " + str(attempts) + " attempt"
        print
        print "------------------------------------------------"
        print   
    else:
        print""
        print "Your card is unfortunately now blocked" 
        exit()
```

There are other places where you can place the function like right above the while loop but make sure your function is above the area where it is called.

Comment: As MorganThrapp points out in the comments, this will crash with a NameError as `menu` has not been defined.